# Python PDF>JPG conversion with pdf2jpg

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying convert some PDFs into JPG, and using pdf2jpg to do this.

The code I run is:

```
inputPath = sys.argv[1].replace("\\", "/")
print(inputPath)

# Get parent folder of the file
parentFolder = "/".join(inputPath.split("/")[:-1])
print(parentFolder)

# Convert pdf to jpg in same folder
result = pdf2jpg.convert_pdf2jpg(inputPath, parentFolder, pages="1")
print(result)
```

When I run this, the error I get is:

```
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:/Users/Username/Desktop\\test.pdf'
```

The weird thing is, when I run the same code with the last 2 lines commented out, I get:

```
C:/Users/Username/Desktop/test.pdf
C:/Users/Username/Desktop
```

It seems like the inputPath itself is being converted to forward slashes correctly, but then being reverted to backslashes when being referenced by pdf2jpg.

ETA: Switched to backslashes instead of forward slashes, and using raw literals. Code now as below:

```
inputPath = sys.argv[1]
inputPath_raw = r'%s'%inputPath
print(inputPath_raw)

parentFolder = chr(92).join(inputPath_raw.split(chr(92))[:-1])
print(parentFolder)

result = pdf2jpg.convert_pdf2jpg(inputPath_raw, parentFolder, pages="1")
print(result)
```

Then I give it the input:

```
convert.py "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test.pdf"
```

And the error I see is:

```
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\test.pdf'
```

Printing the variables still gives the correct output as the file paths, it's just this part which fails to recognise the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The problem is that **pdf2jpg** is trying to create a directory, named after your pdf file in the outputpath. When converting the file `test.pdf`, it will (try to) create a directory named `\test.pdf` in the specified outputpath.

Since the source and destination directories are identical it will fail, because it's a filesystem limitation to have a file and a directory with the same name `test.pdf` in the same path.

Here is a test to create the output jpgs in `inputpath` + `\pdf2jpg` dir and it will work:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
import os
import sys
from pdf2jpg import pdf2jpg

source = sys.argv[1]
destination = os.path.dirname(source)+"\pdf2jpg"

try:
    os.mkdir(destination)
except FileExistsError:
    # pdf2jpg directory existing
    pass

result = pdf2jpg.convert_pdf2jpg(source, destination, pages="ALL")
```

Comment: Looks like the same error, the variables print fine but when using them in the pdf2jpg function, additional backslashes are added which cause the same error as previously.

Comment: Thanks! I think the issue might be with pdf2jpg then, as I've done this conversion and the same issue remains.

Comment: Update your post with your new code using raw literals and argv for others to analyse.

Comment: Included both input and output in the edit - thank you for the guidance.

Comment: Thank you! It's throwing a FileNotFoundError now, but I think that's just the OS, meaning the pdf2jpg part is sorted. Cheers!